# .Net Framework Redistributable

Tags: .net, openxml, office-interop, redistributable

Are these DLL's below are included in .Net Framework Redistributable?

> DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll
>
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You can get DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll from the Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office.  The download [is here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&displaylang=en).

The Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll assembly is a COM interop assembly.  It is automatically generated when you use Project + Add Reference and select Microsoft Word from the COM tab.  That won't happen when you've got the Office PIA installed, that's okay.

Comment: +1. I initially missed the fact that Office PIA is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Both are redistributable, but they are not included in the .Net Framework Redistributable.

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll is a Microsoft Office Primary Interop Assembly (can be generated).

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll  is in the Open XML SDK